# exception- Element type "xs:element" must be followed by either attribute specification, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="company">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="companyname"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>



<xs:element name="department"maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="dname"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="deptphoneno"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="deptfaxno"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="deptemail"/>


<xs:element name="employee"maxOcurrs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="empid"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="ename"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="emailid"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="phoneno"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="contractemployee"maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="phoneno"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

/*it throws an exception -  Element type "xs:element" must be followed by either attribute specification, ">" or "/>"

I can,t find what is wrong with the code 
Plz if somebody could rewrite the code without any error*/

Answer (score 2):

Two types of problems exist in your XSD:

1. The immediate error is due to neglecting to add a space between
   attributes:

   ```
   <xs:element name="department"maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
   ```

   Your XSD has two more such errors.
2. `maxOcurs` is misspelled.

Fix those problems and your XSD will be syntactically correct.